# PHP MySqli How to SELECT Everything from a Table for which i don't know the name?

Tags: php, mysql, html, mysqli

I'm working on a personal project something like a document management system.
I'm creating new folders and and table in DB with the same name as the folder.

I can list all of them, and i want when i click on the Table name listed in HTML table, to show everything that's inside that table.

But i don't know the name of the table.

And i'm getting "**0 results**".

- Screenshot of the Database Tables ->
  [DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0k2L.png)
- Screenshot of the "O results"
  -> [Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlhtG.png)
- Screenshot of listing the tables -> [Tables listed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcZRH.png)

However i can see in the URL that i'm in the "correct" table because it says the name of my table.

I know that the issue is somewhere in the SELECT statement from view.php in which i don't know how to select the table that i don't know the name of :-)

Can someone please help me?

Thanks a lot.

This is my index code where i list all of the Tables from DB as buttons:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">

<div class="col-md-4 col-xl-4 text-center ml-sm-2 ml-md-5 ml-lg-5 mt-5">
  <div class="alert alert-danger mb-0"><strong>TABLES from DATABASE:</strong></div>

    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover text-center">

      <tr class="title">
        <th>Folder Name:</th>
      </tr>

  <?php

    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "folder");

    if (!$conn) {
       die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

     $sql = "SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables where table_schema='folder';";
     $result = $conn-> query($sql);

      if ($result) {
      while ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {


      echo "<a href='view.php?". $row['table_name'] ."' ><span style='font-size: 19px; color: #3277b6; margin-right: 15px;'><i class='far fa-eye'></i></span></a>";


    }
              }
          else {
            echo "0 results";
    }

    $conn-> close();

    ?>

    </table>
</div>
```

This is the view.php code:

```
<body>

     <div class="container">
      <div class="row mt-5 ml-5">

       <div class="col-md-8 col-xl-11 text-center ml-sm-2 ml-md-5 ml-lg-5 mt-5">
         <div class="alert alert-danger mb-0">
           <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-dark mr-5" role="button">Go Back</a>
      </div>

       <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
         <table class="table table-bordered table-hover text-center">
            <tr>
              <th>Name:</th>
               <th>Create at:</th>
            </tr>

<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "folder");

if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables where table_name = ?";
$result = $conn-> query($sql);

if ($result) {
while ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<tr>
         <td>".$row['name']."</td>
         <td>".$row['created_at']."</td>
      </tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
}
else {
echo "0 results";
}

$conn-> close();

?>

                      </table>

                      </div>

                      </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JSs -->
        <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/theme-script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This code make no sense : `$sql = "SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables where table_name = ?";
$result = $conn-> query($sql);`  
You need to set the table_name value, by using a prepared statement and binding a value to it. Also, you should change your url to something like`view.php?table=' . $row['table_name']` in order to retrieve it easily with the $_GET variable

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and ideally should not be used in new code.

Comment: Consider using a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) to solve problems like this. These give you patterns to follow for organizing your code into proper model, view and controller contexts and avoids ending up with a confused stew of concerns, with HTML, PHP, SQL, and JavaScript all jumbled together. Frameworks come in many forms from really lean like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to exceptionally full-featured like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) and many spots in between.

Comment: Why not just have `folder` be a column of your content table?

Comment: @mario how do you mean?

Comment: @mario I agree, it would be far more simple to have a table, lets call it users, with an id, a name and a created_at column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following line:

```
echo "<a href='view.php?". $row['table_name'] ."' ><span style='font-size: 19px; color: #3277b6; margin-right: 15px;'><i class='far fa-eye'></i></span></a>";
```

to

```
echo "<a href='view.php?table_name=". $row['table_name'] ."' ><span style='font-size: 19px; color: #3277b6; margin-right: 15px;'><i class='far fa-eye'></i></span></a>";
```

And then change the following line:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables where table_name = ?";
```

to

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables where table_name = '{$_REQUEST['table_name']}'";
```

The caveat is that this is a pretty big security risk as it is, and you *need* to ensure that the variable is cleaned up before injecting it in to your SQL code.

Final thing, you're not actually doing any error catching, so change this:

```
else {
echo "0 results";
}
```

to

```
else {
echo $conn->error;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @dearsina  I change that but it still says "0 results" :/

Comment: As you point, it is far better to use [prepared queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) for the last part

Comment: @Blagojce, try this, right after the $sql variable has been defined, do var_dump(), take the SQL query and run it in phpMyAdmin, and see what kind of results you get.

Comment: @Adrien, absolutely. Or some serious filtering of the variable.

Comment: @dearsina this is what i'm getting in [phpmysql](https://i.imgur.com/kdkOeLt.png).  
And this is what i'm getting in my [table](https://i.imgur.com/wmmsr78.png)

Comment: @Blagojce Your PHP code is working. It is returning results. However, there is no `$row['name']`. Do a var_dump() of $row and see what columns are available to you.

Comment: @Blagojce the query string is intented to be used in PHP and cannot be used like that in a SQL query on PHPMyAdmin, $_REQUEST['table_name'] will be remplaced with the table name

Comment: @Blagojce it should be TABLE_NAME and CREATE_TIME instead of name and created_at according to the docs : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/tables-table.html

Comment: @dearsina and Adrien this is what i have in my tables (https://i.imgur.com/f6yFXIJ.png)

Comment: Oh dear, are you trying to query your _table_? Ok, your SQL query should instead be `SELECT * FROM {$_REQUEST['table_name']}`.

Comment: In this case what you want is doing `SELECT * FROM {$_REQUEST['table_name']}` but I think you should reconsider your database structure

Comment: @Blagojce, I'm glad we got that sorted. Please read up on SQL injections before going live with any of this code.

Comment: @dearsina one more question. In my index page where i'm listing the tables names from the db in html table, instead of just having a fontawesome icon, how can i have a button with the name of the table? This line:

`echo "<a href='view.php?table_name=". $row['table_name'] ."' ><span style='font-size: 19px; color: #3277b6; margin-right: 15px;'><i class='far fa-eye'></i></span></a>";`

Comment: Give the <a> tag the following class `class="btn btn-primary"`. If you have bootstrap set up correctly, The link should become a button.

Comment: @dearsina i did that but it's still not giving the name of the table inside the [button](https://i.imgur.com/Fy0sthz.png)

Comment: @dearsina sorry i figure it out. i added ". $row['table_name'] ." Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT " .$varible. " FROM information_schema.tables where table_schema='folder'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```